# How to disable windows-to-window snapping in Gnome 3 desktop?

Tags: gnome3

I really like Gnome 3, except some minor things, one of them being this:

In Gnome 3, windows snaps to other windows and it is really annoying to me. Snapping windows to screen edges is nice, but this window-to-window snapping is making me crazy, it feels like frame drops/lag when moving windows around on the desktop.

Do I have to fork gnome 3 to keep my sanity or can this feature be turned off?
(using Gnome 3.16.2)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this actually. See here: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/35544484-window-edge-resistance-snapping-not-tiling-no-way-to-disable

This link basically says there is no option to disable this, so this is the default and only behavior. I added a $15 bounty to have it fixed, as well as a comment on bugzilla, no idea if it helps. bugzilla link: bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=679609

Comment: what does it say?

Comment: You cannot access the link? It basically says there is no option to disable this, so this is the default and only behavior. I added a $15 bounty to have it fix as well as a comment on bugzilla, no idea if it helps.

bugzilla link: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=679609

Answer (score 1):

Go into the terminal and input:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
```

Comment: does not work on 3.16 for me. Value being set, but no effect, also after restart

Comment: Thanks but this does not disable window snapping, this instead disables the behavior of dragging windows to screen edges (same as super + arrow keyboard shortcut).

Answer (score 1):

Found two workarrounds (not a fix) to this:

A) To avoid windows snapping (tiling) to each other in the center when using the monitor edge snapping for two windows, you can put another small window in between them, which will avoid the snapping of windows from happening. Afterwards you can just close that window.

B) If two windows are already snapped you can also minimize one of them then change size of the other then maximize again, that also seems to break up the annoying window tiling/snapping.